# Is there a large colimit-sketch for topological spaces?

Tags: reference-request, ct.category-theory, gn.general-topology, limits-and-colimits, sketches

**Question.** Is there a large [colimit-sketch](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/sketch) $\mathcal{S}$ such that $\mathrm{Mod}(\mathcal{S}) \simeq \mathbf{Top}$?

In other words, is there a category $\mathcal{E}$ with a class of cocones $\mathcal{S}$ in $\mathcal{E}$ such that topological spaces can be seen as those functors $\mathcal{E} \to \mathbf{Set}$ which map the cocones in $\mathcal{S}$ to colimit cocones? Since the forgetful functor $\mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Set}$ creates colimits, I don't see any a priori reason why this cannot be true.

Let me explain a bit where this question comes from, since I also have some reference requests about related questions. Burroni has given in *Esquisses des catégories à limites et des quasi-topologies* ([zBMATH review](https://zbmath.org/?q=an:0395.18005), see also Burroni's [1970 CR note](http://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k5619186c/f24.item)) a large mixed sketch based on filter convergence (see [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/277329/)) whose models are topological spaces. Maybe this thesis contains other sketches as well, perhaps even a colimit-sketch, thus answering my question, but I could not find it online anywhere, and Ehresmann told me that, in fact, there is no digital copy. I was quite surprised to find out that there is actually a limit-sketch for topological spaces. This is explicitly mentioned by Guitart in *Toute théorie est algébrique et topologique* (Proposition 25, [pdf](https://webusers.imj-prg.fr/%7Erene.guitart/docpp/guitart08tteaet.pdf)), without proof, but the construction comes out of Edgar's description of topological spaces in *The class of topological spaces is equationally definable* (doi:[10.1007/BF02945113](https://doi.org/10.1007/BF02945113)), which in turn is based on Kelley's characterization of topological spaces in terms of net convergence (*General topology*,  Chapter 2, Theorem 9): A topological space can be described as a set $X$ together with a monomorphism $C(P,X) \to X^P \times X$ for every directed set $P$ satisfying four axioms (think of $C(P,X)$ as the set of $P$-indexed convergent nets including their limits). These axioms can be written down in categorical language. For example, the axiom "subnets converge to the same point" is the following: for every cofinal map $Q\to P$ there is a morphism $C(P,X) \to C(Q,X)$ such that
$$\begin{array}{cc} C(P,X) & \rightarrow & X^P \times X \\ \downarrow && \downarrow \\ C(Q,X) & \rightarrow & X^Q \times X \end{array}$$
commutes. I have written down all the details of that sketch, but I wonder (**Side question**) if this limit-sketch is written down somewhere else already? As a byproduct we get the notion of a *topological space object internal to any complete category* (not just a topos as studied by Macfarlane and Stout for instance).  Let me also mention that I found out that $\mathbf{Top}^{\mathrm{op}}$ is the category of models of a large limit-sketch, which means, however, that $\mathbf{Top}$ is the category of $\mathbf{Set}^{\mathrm{op}}$-valued models of a large colimit-sketch. Please let me know if you know any other references about this topic apart from those already mentioned.

*Edit. Details of the sketches mentioned above can now be found in [Large limit sketches and topological space objects](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.11115).

Comment: The limit sketch sounds like Barr's [relational $\beta$-module](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/relational+beta-module) description of $Top$, though I guess I've never seen anybody actually write that out as a sketch. I've never heard of anybody studying colimit sketches without also allowing limit cones in the desription -- the hierarchy is always limit sketches -> general sketches. Is there an interesting example of a category (which is not  presheaf category) sketchable with _just_ colimits?

Comment: @TimCampion Thank you for your comment. Barr' description is based on ultrafilters, Burroni's on filters, and I think that the description with net convergence is not just different, but *way simpler*. As for the examples: maybe later :)

Comment: An interesting question and complete answer, both with 0 upvotes... slow night, eh? (+1 each, cool stuff)

Comment: Macfarlane's thesis _Topological objects in elementary topoi_ is here: https://unsworks.unsw.edu.au/fapi/datastream/unsworks:61319/SOURCE01?view=true, Stout's *second* paper, _Topological space objects in a topos II: $\varepsilon$-Completeness and $\varepsilon$-cocompleteness_ is here: https://doi.org/10.1007/BF01154279. It's not clear that the first paper was actually published, it is cited in the second paper as "to appear". Stout's thesis is at https://www.ideals.illinois.edu/handle/2142/64888

Comment: @theHigherGeometer Thanks for adding the references to the post, I was a bit too lazy for that, I must admit. By the way, do we already "know" each other? Have you been on mathoverflow under a different name?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Yes, I'm David Roberts. I tried out changing my username (it's the name of my blog) just to see how I liked it, but I'm waiting to change back—there's a temporary lock after each change.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is **no**. I think this example illustrates why pure colimit sketches are rarely studied; one generally allows limits into the sketch *before* generalizing to allow colimits into the sketch. That is, I think this example illustrates the point that pure colimit-sketches are just not that useful. (This is after already noting that categories like $Grp$ and such can't be so sketched because they fail to have disjoint coproducts).

Here is the argument. Suppose that $Top$ were the category of models of a colimit sketch $(\mathcal E, \mathcal S)$. Then because colimits commute with colimits (and colimits in functor categories are computed levelwise), the representables $Hom(E,-): Set^{\mathcal E} \to Set$ would restrict to a strong generating class of colimit-preserving functors $Top \to Set$. This contradicts the following

**Claim:** Every colimit-preserving functor $F: Top \to Set$ carries the canonical map $S \to I$ to an isomorphism.

Here and in the following, $S$ is the [Sierpinski space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sierpi%C5%84ski_space), and $I$ is the [indiscrete space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trivial_topology) on two points, and $1,2$ are the discrete spaces on 1 and 2 elements respectively. And $C_2$ denotes the group with two elements. Note that $2$ and $I$ each have a natural $C_2$ action, both with quotient $1$, and that the map $2 \to I$ is $C_2$-equivariant.

**Proof:** Let $X = F(1)$. Because $F$ preserves coproducts, we have $F(2) = X \amalg X$. Moreover, the $C_2$ action on $X \amalg X$ is free, so we may write $F(2) = C_2 \times X$ as a $C_2$-set. Now, because $F$ preserves epimorphisms, we have that $F(I)$ is a $C_2$-equivariant quotient of $F(2)$ which has $F(1)$ as a further $C_2$-equivariant quotient. Therefore $F(I) = (C_2 \times X_0) \amalg X_1$ as a $C_2$-set, for some decomposition $X = X_0 \amalg X_1$.

Now consider the pushout $I = S \cup_2 S$, using the two bijections $\phi,\psi: 2 \rightrightarrows S$. Because $F$ preserves epimorphisms and because the map $F(2) \to F(I)$ factors through $F(S)$, we have $F(S) = (C_2 \times X_{00}) \amalg X_{01} \amalg X_1$ for some decomposition $X_0 = X_{00} \amalg X_{01}$, and $F(\phi)$ is the obvious quotient map. Moreover, because $\psi = \phi \sigma$, (where $\sigma$ denotes the action of the nontrivial element of $C_2$), we have that $F(\psi)$ differs from $F(\phi)$ only in that it applies $\sigma$ to the elements of the $C_2 \times X_{00}$ factor.

Observe, then that $F(\psi) = \tau F(\phi)$, where $\tau$ is this residual $C_2$ action (even though there is no such factorization before applying $F$ -- $S$ does not have a nontrivial $C_2$-action even though $F(S)$ does). Therefore, the pushout $F(I) = F(S) {}_{F(\phi)}\cup_{F(\psi)} F(S)$ is isomorphic to the pushout $F(S) {}_{F(\phi)} \cup_{F(\phi)} F(S)$. But since $F(\phi)$ is an epimorhism, pushing it out against itself yields an isomorphism. That is, either map $F(S) \rightrightarrows F(I)$ is a bijection as claimed.

Comment: The representable $\mathrm{Hom}(E,-)$ is an object of $Set^{\mathcal{E}}$, not a functor $Set^{\mathcal{E}} \to Set$. But I assume you mean the evaluation functor $Set^{\mathcal{E}} \to Set$, $F \mapsto F(E)$. And this is represented by the representable (sic!) functor $\mathrm{Hom}(E,-) \in Set^{\mathcal{E}}$. When we restrict these evaluation functors to $\mathrm{Mod}(\mathcal{S})$, why do they form a strong generator (are you using a different definition here?). Also these restrictions don't need to be representable anymore: the $\mathrm{Hom}(E,-)$ are models iff $\mathcal{S}$ is realized.

Comment: But perhaps we don't need that these functors are representable at all, and don't need a notion of generator. The evaluation functors $\mathrm{Mod}(\mathcal{S}) \to Set$, $F \mapsto F(E)$ are *jointly conservative*, and cocontinuous. So a necessary condition for a category $\mathcal{A}$ to be the category of models of a colimit-sketch is that there is a jointly conservative class of cocontinuous functors $\mathcal{A} \to Set$. And this is not the case when $\mathcal{A}$ has a morphism, which is not an isomorphism, but mapped to an isomorphism by any cocontinuous functor $\mathcal{A} \to Set$.

Comment: Unfortunately the rest of the proof is even harder for me to digest. Why do we have the decomposition of $F(I)$? What do you mean by "collapse some $C_2$ orbits and nothing more"? What does "pushing this map out against itself" mean?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: I guess by “a strongly generating class of functors Top —> Set”, Tim had in mind “…jointly faithful…”, since “strongly generating class of objects” = “jointly faithful representables”.  Re the rest of the proof: “collapse some $C_2$ orbits and nothing more” means “induces an iso on the $C_2$-quotient”.  Generally for the second paragraph, I’d say: draw the pushout square $I = S +_2 S$.  The two maps $F(2) \to F(S)$ of the co-span are epis, and isomorphic to each other.  So it’s a cokernel square of an epi, so the pushout inclusions $F(S) \to F(I)$ are isos.

Comment: (1) The note about representables versus evaluation functors is correct; I was identifying $E$ with its image under Yoneda as usual. (2) These functors are indeed unlikely to be representable in $Mod(S)$. (3) I usually use "generating class of functors" as a synonym of "jointly faithful class of functors" and "strongly generating class of functors" when the functors are additionally jointly conservative. In this case, it can be seen because $Mod(S)$ is a full subcategory of $Set^E$, where these functors are already strongly generating. (4) Peter has interpreted my later intent correctly.

Comment: One thing I did not make clear is how the situation after applying $F$ differs from the situation before applying $F$ -- in both cases the two maps $2 \rightrightarrows S$ are the same "up to an automorphism", but in the former case we _can't_ pretend they're the same map because that automorphism lives on the _domain_ of the maps. In the latter case we can, though, because after applying $F$ we can also regard the two maps $F(2) \rightrightarrows F(S)$ as being the same up to an automorphism on the _codomain_. This justifies pretending they're the same map when taking the pushout.

Comment: Thank you. I still don't get it, starting from the decomposition of $F(I)$. I don't see where it comes from.

Comment: Already for $F=$ forgetful functor I don't see it.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Thanks for asking -- I think there are several things I did not expain very will here. One thing I left kind of implicit is that $I$ also admits a $C_2$-action and $2 \to I$ is an equivariant map. So $F(2) \to F(I)$ is a $C_2$-equivariant surjection. Moreover, the surjection can't identify elements in different orbits because the codiagonal map $F(2) \to F(1)$ factors through it, and does not identify elements in different orbits. It folllows that $F(2) \to F(I)$ merely collapses certain $C_2$-orbits and nothing more, i.e. that the indicated decomposition holds.

Comment: In the case where $F$ is the forgetful functor, $X$ is a 1-point set, and we have $X_0 = X$, $X_1 = \emptyset$.

Comment: @TimCampion Thank you very much for your patience. I think I have understood your proof now. I needed to remember that $C_2$-sets (aka involutions) are very easy to classify: the decompose into a free part and a fixed point part. Your decompositions move the free part, step by step, into the fixed point part.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg Exactly. Yeah, and I think the crux of the proof is the point where the factorization $F(\psi) = \tau F(\phi)$ appears, which I don't really have a conceptual explanation for -- it's just a matter of leaning very heavily on this ability to classify $C_2$-sets so easily and explicitly work with them. I would be interested if there were a cleaner way to do it.

Comment: I have found a much more general approach, but will probably write down the details elsewhere.

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg You're right, I didn't spell this out. Suppose that $(M_j)_{j \in J}$ is a diagram in $Mod(S)$, and let $M = \varinjlim_j M_j$ be the levelwise colimit. Let $(x_i \to x)_{i \in I}$ be a sketched cocone. Then $M(x) = \varinjlim_j M_j(x) = \varinjlim_j \varinjlim_i M_j(x_i) = \varinjlim_i \varinjlim_j M_j(x_i) = \varinjlim_i M(x_i)$, so that $M \in Mod(S)$. That is, colimits in $Mod(S)$ are computed "levelwise", i.e. the evaluation functors $M \mapsto M(A)$ commute with colimits in $Mod(S)$.

Comment: Sorry I deleted my comment already, because I saw that there is no problem after all. Thank you for adding the proof.

Answer (score 9):

Isbell shows in *[Function spaces and adjoints](https://www.mscand.dk/article/view/11581/9597)* (1975) that every cocontinuous functor $\mathbf{Top} \to \mathbf{Set}$ is a coproduct of copies of the forgetful functor. (I have found an alternative proof for this within a more general theory, details will be added here when it's online.) But a necessary condition for a category to be modelled by a (possibly large) colimit sketch is  that the cocontinuous functors to $\mathbf{Set}$ are jointly conservative. By picking any bijective continuous map which is not an isomorphism, we get a contradiction.

*Edit. An alternative proof can be found in my new paper [*Large limit sketches and topological space objects*](https://arxiv.org/abs/2106.11115) (2021), Theorem 8.7.